# How can divide every element of an array by the sum of the array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
propensity = [32.  0.  0.]
```

I've calculated the sum of the array as follows:

```
a0 = sum(propensity)
```

I'm trying to calculate a fraction for every element of the array over the sum of the array and have written the following function:

```
def prob_rxn_fires(propensity, a0):
for x in propensity:
    print("propensity:\n", x)  
    prob = x/a0  
print("Prob reaction fires:\n", prob)      
return prob
```

I want the function to return three fractions for each array element, at the moment it only returns 0. I think that's because when it iterates through the array and reaches the return statement it returns only the last value it computed which is 0/32 = 0.0. I need to return the first 2 values as well but am unsure how to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `numpy`?

```
import numpy as np

propensity = np.array([32.0,  0.0,  0.0])
propensity/sum(propensity)
```

#### Output:

```
array([1., 0., 0.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply as

```
propensity = [32.,  0.0,  0.0]
a0 = sum(propensity)
propensity = [x/a0 for x in propensity]
print(propensity)
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: This technique might run into low-level issues as the `propensity` iterable is being iterated **and** written in parallel.  Consider revising.

Comment: What sort of low level issues ? ,I think only checkfor division by zero needs to be added , and also for your solution why to import numpy for such simple task

Comment: TBH I cannot remember all the details.  From what I remember, when Python assigns an iterable to a hash table, sometimes the loop will not continue as it considers the next value as already seen, so exits prematurely - due to the order in which hash values are stored.  **Suggestion:** Just assign your list comp output to another variable.